# Error executing action `install` on resource 'windows_feature[AD-Domain-Services]' - on Windows server 2016 chef run with windows_feature resource

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

error: `` Error executing action `install` on resource 'windows_feature[AD-Domain-Services]' ``
^ this happens on all windows features when installing them via windows_feature resource on windows server 2016.

Chef version:

```
Chef Development Kit Version: 3.2.30
chef-client version: 14.4.56
delivery version: master (6862f27aba89109a9630f0b6c6798efec56b4efe)
berks version: 7.0.6
kitchen version: 1.23.2
inspec version: 2.2.70
```

And my kitchen.yml:

```
driver:
  name: vagrant
  boot_timeout: 600
provisioner:
  name: chef_solo
#  name: chef_zero
#  require_chef_omnibus: 14.6.47
  retry_on_exit_code:
    - 35
  max_retries: 3
  multiple_converge: 3
  wait_for_retry: 600
platforms:
  - name: windows2012r2
    driver:
      box: mwrock/Windows2016
      box_url: mwrock/Windows2016
suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[windows_ad::default]
#      - recipe[windows_ad::configure_domain]
    retry_on_exit_code:
    - 35
    max_retries: 3
    multiple_converge: 3
    wait_for_retry: 600
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by switching out the windows server 2016 vagrant image that I was using for the 100th time...

The working code looks like:

```
  [
    'AD-Domain-Services',
    'DNS',
    'FileAndStorage-Services',
    'File-Services',
     ....
     ....
  ].each do |feature|
    windows_feature feature do
      action :install
      install_method :windows_feature_powershell
      all true
    end
  end
else
  [
    'NetFx3',
    'Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ServerAdminTools-Update',
    'DirectoryServices-DomainController'
  ].each do |feature|
    windows_feature feature do
      action :install
      install_method :windows_feature_powershell
    end
  end
end
```

and the new image that also works is `jacqinthebox/windowsserver2016`

Answer (score 0):

This is some working code we use to install a selection of Windows Features:

```
features = ['Web-WebServer',                    # Web Server
            'Web-Windows-Auth',                 # Windows Authentication
            'Web-Mgmt-Tools',                   # Management Tools
            'Web-WMI',                          # IIS 6 WMI Compatibility
            'Web-Mgmt-Compat',                  # IIS 6 Management Compatibility
            'NET-Framework-Features',           # .NET Framework 3.5 Features
            'NET-Framework-45-Features',        # .NET Framework 4.5 Features
            'NET-WCF-Services45']               # WCF Services

windows_feature 'Install App Server Features' do
  feature_name features
  action :install
  install_method :windows_feature_powershell
  source node['windows_feature_source']
end
```

You will note that we also specify the `source` for the Windows Features (read from an attribute we have set) as we strip the source off our servers and instead point to a remote fileshare - this may be the issue you are having. You can also remove the `source` property if you know the source files are on the server.